# How to integrate a MetaMask Wallet into your Website

Tags: metamask, nft

i want to build a browsergame, where you are able to connect with your MetaMask wallet as a Account, like OpenSea does it for example. It is not for transactions but for authorization reason.

Does somebody know how to do that in big points?

Answer (score -1):

For doing Ethereum wallet based logins, please see

- [Sign-in with Ethereum](https://login.xyz/)

However your question is too open-ended to be a practical programming question that is answerable on StackOverflow Q&A format. I suggest you go to Sign-in with Ethereum Discord for open-ended discussion.